# Changing the formatter of Icon/Button Columns

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Regarding this example here http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/format#icon

In the `cellClick` function, how can you change the icon used in the formatter?

The use-case is simply changing a folder icon to folder-open when a cell is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple, track the state in the rowData ...

https://jsfiddle.net/hgwz4knp/

```js
cellClick:function(e, cell){
   let row = cell.getRow();
   let data = row.getData();

   row.update({openClosed:data.openClosed ^ 1});

   this.redraw(true); 
},
formatter:function(cell, fP, onR){
   let data = cell.getData();

   if (data.openClosed == 1){
      return "<i class='fas fa-folder-open'></i>";
   }else{
      return "<i class='fas fa-folder'></i>";
   }
},
```

Comment: I had a hunch I could track state in rowData, thanks! I will see if this will play well with paging and header filtering. I noticed weird bugs with cellClick when filters are invalid for example.

Comment: Also FYI looks like `this.redraw()` is not a thing in 5.0.4.

Comment: Should be...http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/layout#redraw, but 5.0 is in alpha, could be MANY bugs

Comment: wait, 5.0 isnt alpha anymore ? I didnt even see it go through beta !?!?

Comment: Yeah I think 5 is officially released and is not alpha or beta or anything.

Comment: Its still a bit buggy though, I have two issues out on the issue tracker right now. One is literally broken on their example page.

Comment: As of the 5.1 release things are a lot smoother now